# Using Tkinter to assign filename to variable

Tags: python, variables, tkinter

I would like to be able to use tkinter entry to allow the user to type in the name of a file. That file is stored in a variable, which is then used to run a validation program I have been working on.  With the code I have now, though, I simply get an invalid file error, and the code does not run.

```
TypeError: invalid file: <function input_text at 0x035DBD68>
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
def input_text():
    mtext = stuff.get
    label2 = Label(root,text=mtext).pack()
    return

root = Tk()
stuff = StringVar()

root.title("Project")
root.geometry('300x100')

label = Label(root,text="My Project").pack()
button1 = Button(root,text="OK",command=input_text).pack()
entry1 = Entry(root,textvariable=stuff).pack()

with open(input_text, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
```

The idea is that the code under the with statement will not execute until input_text is assigned, but I can't find a way to do this.

Comment: BTW: always put in question FULL error message (Traceback), not only its last part. There are other usefull information. ie. it shows which line makes problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want some code to run after a button click, then put it inside of your method.

Also, `input_text` is defined as function and `open` expects a file as your error states. You might want to use your `mtext` or `StringVar`'s content directly as filename.

```
def input_text():
    mtext = stuff.get() #notice the parentheses. You need to call the get method
    label2 = Label(root,text=mtext).pack()
    with open(mtext, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)


root = Tk()
stuff = StringVar()

root.title("Project")
root.geometry('300x100')

label = Label(root,text="My Project").pack()
button1 = Button(root,text="OK",command=input_text).pack()
entry1 = Entry(root,textvariable=stuff).pack()
```

Note that, if you want to access opened file outside of that method, you should make it global or use class structure.